# Is Fuse ESB an opensource?

Tags: java, esb, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Bit confused if Fuse ESB is open source or not. The Fuse site says it is an open source but when I try to download it, I am redirected to Red Hat site. On the Red Hat site I can't see any open source link and can only download Fuse ESB enterprise 90 day evaluation version.

Comment: Not sure whats up now. Before the acquisition as far as in know all downloads were free. A subscription was required for support only.

Comment: The license seems to be apache license but I can not find the source code. Can someone point me to the fuse/redhat source code of fuse ESB? They do not seem to build from the apache sources and seem to have their own private patches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Fuse ESB is and has always been open source and continues to be ASL licenses. No changes what so ever there.

The binary downloads is now hosted on Red Hat sites.

Answer (score 2):

Fuse ESB is what became of Apache ServiceMix.

If you install Apache Karaf (formerly known as ServiceMix Kernel) then provision Camel, CXF, and ActiveMQ into, you'll pretty much have the open source version of Fuse ESB, from what I can tell.

Comment: Apache ServiceMix is an Apache project (http://servicemix.apache.org/) and FUSE ESB is based on it, different and not related with Apache (http://fusesource.com/community/apache-committers-and-fuse/). they prepare different versions: integrated, tested, verified, etc. it is well explained in this paper (http://fusesource.com/collateral/download/50).